# How can I change the modifier to open search results in a new tab in Firefox back to Alt?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

I've gotten used to pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open search results in a new tab using the Firefox search bar. With the last update the modifier key changed to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. How can I change it back to <kbd>Alt</kbd>?

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible to open search in a new tab by using Enter alone. In [about:config](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config), right-click and Toggle [browser.search.openintab](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries#Browser.) to true.

Answer (score 0):

vWil led me to the right answer. I had browser.search.openintab set to true, which makes searches open in a new tab when pressing Enter or Ctrl+Enter, but open in the same tab when pressing Alt+Enter. 
Now I toggled browser.search.openintab to false, which makes searches open in a new tab when pressing Alt+Enter, but in the same tab when pressing Ctrl+Enter or Enter, which is the behavior I want.